# Loading JSON file contents wih Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to load content from a JSON file to an HTML page using jQuery / Javascript.

Whenever I try to load the page, there's an empty page.

This is the code:

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="products">

</div>
<script>
    var my_json;
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON('products.ajson', function(data) {
            var output="<ul>";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; ++i) {
                output+="<li>" + data.Products[i].Name + " " + data.Products[i].Album + "--" + data.Products[i].Label+ data.Products[i].Tracks + data.Products[i].Price + data.Products[i].Genre+"</li>";
            }

            output+="</ul>";
            document.getElementById("products").innerHTML=output;

        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**products.json**

```
{
    "Products": [
        { "Name": "Pink Floyd",
            "Album": "The Best Of Pink Floyd: A Foot In The Door",
            "Label": "EMI UK",
            "Tracks":"Hey You, See Emily Play, The Happiest Days Of Our Lives, Another Brick in The Wall (Part 2), Have a cigar, Wish You Where Here, Time, The Great Gig in the Sky, Money, Comfortably Numb, High Hopes, Learning to Fly, The Fletcher Memorial Home, Shine On You Crazy Diamond, Brain Damage, Eclipse" ,
            "Price": "16.40",
            "Genre": "Rock"

        },
        {
            "Name": "Depeche Mode",
            "Album": "A Question Of Time",
            "Label": "Mute",
            "Tracks":"A Question Of Time, Black Celebration, Something To Do, Stripped, More Than A Party, A Question Of Time(extended), Black Celebration" ,
            "Price": "4.68" ,
            "Genre": "Rock"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Burial",
            "Album": "Street Halo/Kindred",
            "Label": "Hyperdub Japan",
            "Tracks":"Street Halo, NYC, Stolen Dog, Kindred, Loner, Ashtray Wasp" ,
            "Price": "14.06",
            "Genre": "Future Garage"

        },

        {
            "Name": "Aphex Twin",
            "Album": "I Care Because You Do",
            "Label": "1972 US",
            "Tracks":"Acrid Avid Jam Shared, The Waxen Pith, Wax The Nip, Icct Hedral (edit),  Ventolin (video version), Come On You Slags, Start As You Mean To Go On, Wet Tip Hen Ax, Mookid, Alberto Balsalm ,  Cow Cud Is A Twin, Next Heap With " ,
            "Price": "21.10",
            "Genre": "Electronica"
        },

        {
            "Name": "Daft Punk",
            "Album": "Discovery",
            "Label": "",
            "Tracks":"One More Time,  Aerodynamic, Digital Love, Harder Better Faster Stronger, Crescendolls , Nightvision,  Superheroes, High Life ,Something About Us,  Voyager ,Veridis Quo, Short Circuit, Face To Face," ,
            "Price": "23.44"   ,
            "Genre": "Nu-Disco"
        },

        {
            "Name": "Jean Michelle Jarre",
            "Album": "Oxegene 2010",
            "Label": "Oxegene",
            "Tracks":"Oxegene 2010" ,
            "Price": "8.20",
            "Genre": "Ambient"
        },

        {
            "Name": "Joy Division",
            "Album": "In The Studio With Martin Hannett",
            "Label": "Interstate",
            "Tracks":"Digital Full Track,  Noise Drums Sine Warm-up,  Square Heat Ambience Workout, Glass - Breakout Full Track, Synth Ambience Warm-up, Ambience Atmosphere Warm-up, Atmosphere Setting Up, Drums & Bass Full Atmosphere Warm-up Silence, Atmosphere Full Track Metronome Intro - Hannett Intro Question Etc, Metronome Initial Adjustments #1, Metronome Initial Adjustments #2 Industrial Build Up Etc, Dead Souls Sound Check Drums Recognition Check, Dead Souls + Metronome Intro Adjustment Full Track Etc, Cups Smash 'Synth Filters Sweeps' Take #1, Hannett Interview Something Fishy, Ice Age Bass Ambience Warm-up, Full Track Ice Age, Bass Intro Noise Ambience, Clapping Drums Clapping Prog N4 Complete Full Track + Noise, Full Track N4 Programming + Noises, Full Eternal Track,  More N4 Drum Programming Bass Guitar, N4 Industrial, N4 More Warm Up, Digital Ambience Warmth  Rooms Warm-up - Shakin Speaker Dust Off" ,
            "Price": "22.27",
            "Genre": "Rock"
        },

        {
            "Name": "Anthony Rother",
            "Album": "Mother",
            "Label": "Datapunk Germany",
            "Tracks":"Mother, Cinema" ,
            "Price": "10.54",
            "Genre": "Electro"
        },

        {
            "Name": "Gorillaz",
            "Album": "Plastic Beach",
            "Label": "EMI UK",
            "Tracks":"Orchestral Intro,  Welcome To The World Of The Plastic Beach, White Flag, Rhinestone Eyes, Stylo, Superfast Jellyfish, Empire Ants,  Glitter Freeze, Some Kind Of Nature, On Melancholy Hill,  Broken, Sweepstakes ,  Plastic Beach ,  To Binge , Cloud Of Unknowing , Pirate Jet " ,
            "Price": "7.02" ,
            "Genre": "Hip Hop"
        },

        {
            "Name": "Eminem",
            "Album": "Recovery",
            "Label": "",
            "Tracks":"Cold Wind Blows, Talkin' 2 Myself (feat Kobe),  On Fire , Won't Back Down (feat P!nk) ,WTP , Going Through Changes ,  Not Afraid , Seduction, No Love (feat Lil Wayne) ,  Space Bound ,  Cinderella Man , To Life, So Bad ,  Almost Famous ,  Love The Way You Lie (feat Rihanna) , You're Never Over, rack 17" ,
            "Price": "19.92",
            "Genre": "Hip Hop"

        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: why are you placing jquery inside the products div?

Comment: While it's not an error, this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` should be directly above your own script tag - not in the "middle" of the page.

Comment: Open your console.. check to make sure you aren't getting any console errors.  Add an error handler to the ajax call so you can see if the ajax call is successful or erroring out somewhere..  Check to make sure you are getting back the JSON in the response

Answer (score 1):

You've got `products.Products` and `Products.products` backward. The return variable is `products`, which has a property called `Products`. You need to call it `products.Products`.

Maybe to avoid ambiguity, call your result variable `result` or something, so you can say `result.Products`.

Also, I'd recommend a standard `for` loop instead of a `for..in` loop. If there are any other properties assigned to the `Array` prototype (which is possible - some libraries will assign new functions to the prototype, like `indexOf`), you'll experience problems.

```
for (var i = 0; i < products.Products.length; ++i) {
    // do something with products.Products[i]
}
```

Since this was a javascript error, you would see it by running this through a debugger. Whenever you see weird stuff like this, open up the console (Chrome dev tools, Firebug, IE dev tools, etc.), and it will help you track this stuff down.

Comment: I did as you said previosuly, with the same result, an empty page.

Comment: Works perfectly for me if you rearrange the `products.Products` and `Products.products` variables (all of them). And as long as `products.json` is in the same directory as the HTML page, and IIS is able to serve it up. In addition to watching the console in your debugger, watch the Network tab to make sure the request is actually happening.

Comment: could it be some setting from Firefox? I change everything, include the Products.Products and for loop, and the json file is in the same directory as the html page, however, its not working

Comment: @Brian define "not working". This is a pretty obvious error btw: `for (var i in Products.products) {` - `Products` is undefined - you'll see that in your js console.

Comment: If it's not working, you'll need to run it through a debugger - Firebug is an extension to install on top of Firefox, and will tell you right away what the problem is.

Comment: @JoeEnos I will try using Firebug. Rhanks.

Comment: FYI: When I said "IIS" above, I meant whatever web server you're on, whether that's IIS or Apache or whatever - I'm just stuck in an IIS mode.

Comment: @JoeEnos So I need to install some type of server to use JQuery and JSON? Didn't know that, so far I've been using it without WAMP or XAMPP.

Comment: If you're using `file:///whatever.html`, there's a good chance your browser won't like it. I don't think AJAX calls will work without a real HTTP server.

Comment: @JoeEnos Tried that and I still get nothing. Updated the code!

Comment: Did you get it running on IIS or Apache? Because there's still that. And Firebug (or whatever you're using) should still be able to help you out from here.